# Aligning children views in a column separatly

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a compose Row that contains 2 columns. Inside column2 I have an image that has to be centered vertical and horizontal in that column and underneath it I should have a text. How do I position the text under the image that is centered in column2. Cant find a way to change the column2 children alignment.

[image]

```
//The card content
    Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
        //Column1
        Column(
            Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .padding(start = 16.dp, top = 14.dp, bottom = 14.dp)
        ) {
            ....
        }

//Column2
Column(
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    Image(contentDescription = "",
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_maximize),
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(start = 25.dp, end = 25.dp)
            .height(44.dp)
            .width(44.dp)
            .clickable(
                onClick = {

                }
            )
    )
    //This text needs to ignore vertical arrangement and go under the Image
    Text(
        fontSize = 11.sp,
        color = colorResource(id = seeMoreTextColor),
        text = "See more"
    )
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have two items with `Modifier.weight` on both sides of your circle. As the top one doesn't contains any views, you can use `Spacer`. For the second one, you can use `Box` and place the `Text` inside:

```
Column {
    Spacer(Modifier.weight(1f))
    YourCircle()
    Box(Modifier.weight(1f)) {
        Text("Click here")
    }
}
```